# iptables - NAT/PAT rules for HTTPS, HTTP, RDP, SSH

Tags: networking, router, iptables

I'm trying to set up a gateway/router box and can't seem to get my iptables quite right.  The goal is to have a private network of windows boxes that can talk to WAN for HTTPS, HTTP, and SSH.  I want RDP open for talking to the windows machines from the gateway box, but don't want to do any port forwarding for that from WAN.

Right now I do NAT between my network cards with masquerading, my WAN interface is eth0, and my LAN is eth1.  I can ssh into the box just fine,  however I can't RDP to my machines on the private network, or get HTTP/HTTPS.  The logs say I'm dropping packets with destination port 80/443 when I try to connect to google from the router box.

Currently what I've been trying is:

```
# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
# set up nat
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
# allow DNS lookup
for ip in $DNS
do
    echo "Allowing DNS lookups to server '$ip'"
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
done
# allow http/https, ssh
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# allow private RDP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 3389 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# log for debugging
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

The only thing I can figure is that since I'm doing port address translation, specifying the destination/source ports on my WAN interface isn't cutting it.  Any iptables bosses willing to tell me how much I'm getting wrong?

UPDATE: After reading through my logs and testing, I have some rules that seem to be working.

```
# Flushing all rules
iptables -F  
# Setting default filter policy  
iptables -P INPUT DROP  
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP  
#iptables -P FORWARD DROP  
# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback  
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT  
# set up nat  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
# allow DNS lookup  
for ip in $DNS  
do  
        echo "Allowing DNS lookups to server '$ip'"  
        iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
        iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT  
        iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
        iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT  

    #DNS lookups for NAT  
    iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
    iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
done  

# allow service ports to be forwarded to local network
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,1727,8192,8194,36015 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443,1727,8192,8194,36015 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT  

# allow service ports out/in from WAN  
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  

# allow service ports in, only when outbound connection exists  
# 80 - HTTP ( for yum )  
# 443 - HTTPS ( for yum )  
# 21 - FTP ( for yum )   
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# allow local RDP   
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 3389 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 3389 -m state --state   ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I think that last FORWARD rule for 3389 is unnecessary but I haven't tested that yet.  To address some of the first comments:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -n -v  
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination           
   79  5224 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:3389 state ESTABLISHED   
    1   229 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22,80,443,1727,8192,8194,36015
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 22,80,443,1727,8192,8194,36015 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3389 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   68  7488 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443,21 state NEW,ESTABLISHED   
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3389 
    0     0 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             

Chain LOGGING (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination           
    1   229 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `IPTables-Dropped: ' 
    1   229 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -n -v -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I removed the chunks re: my DNS servers from this output.  The only additions I'd like to make to this configuration is to restrict ssh access to a subnet of ip's, but I'll do that last as it should be trivial.  Thanks for the comments so far, hopefully nothing seems out of place with what I have!

Comment: Could you please do a `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -nvL -t nat` and add the outputs to your question? Thanks. :)

Comment: Do the command above, we, need to see how **iptables** sees the rules, you just placed them in a confusing hodge podge order.

Comment: Under input this should be rule #1  **iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED**  I don't know your DNS setup, but in all likelyhood all your DNS rules are a waste of time.  iptables knows you sent out a DNS request and expects a respond, therefore it falls under the RELATED,ESTABILISHED rule and the dns rules you have are wasting space.

Comment: REMOVE related,established from all other rules in the **INPUT** chain.

Comment: FAIL  **--sports 3389**   source ports are randomly assigned on the INPUT chain and therefore only destination matters.

Comment: I posted the list commands in the above post and tried to reorganize the commands I did use in a more sensible way in my script.  It also looks like I should change all the state rules over to conntrack, and ditch the DNS stuff.

I figured out the randomly assigned ports issue in testing.  Thanks for the feedback!